# How to implement the multiple selection in uitable in swift3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uilongpressgesturerecogni

currently, i have added a long press gesture to my table view. It is working fine. Now the thing i want is that if i long press any UITableview cell that cell should get selected and after this if i tap on next cells that too should get selected too.
Below is the code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Label"

        return cell
}


    @IBAction func longPress(_ guesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        if guesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
            print("Long Press")
        }
    }
```

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve. You can use **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**  for selecting cells

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `tableView`'s `allowsMultipleSelection` property in your `longPress` method. Since the longPress won't trigger the `cell`'s selection you can you can use the `gesture`'s location in the `tableView` to get the initial cell that corresponds to the longPress action.

```
func longPress(sender:UILongPressGestureRecognizer)  {
    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        let point = sender.location(in: tableView)
        selectCellFromPoint(point: point)
    default:break
    }
}

func selectCellFromPoint(point:CGPoint) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point) {
        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
    }
}
```